# mongoidでN+1回避のincludesが、2回目以降の実行時には無視される

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

環境
・Rails4.2系
・mongoid 4系 / 5系どちらも

N+1問題を避けるために、`includes`を利用しているのですが、なぜか2回目以降にその設定が無視されてしまいます。使い方が間違っているのでしょうか？

サンプル：PlanモデルとEyecatchモデルがあり、has_oneな関係です。

```
class Plan
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_one :eyecatch
  field :title, type: String
end

class Eyecatch
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :plan
  field :name, type: String
end

plans = Plan.includes(:eyecatch)
plans.each{|p| p p.eyecatch.name } # これは2回のクエリ発行で済む

plans.each{|p| p p.eyecatch.name } # 再度実行すると、N+1回のクエリ発行になる
```